# Table notes spanning two pages

Tags: longtable, tablenotes

I want the table notes to begin on page 1 and being continued on page 2  (just like the table itself that is continued on the next page).

If the table notes are too long for the first page, then the entire text of table notes is displayed on the next page. So how can I force them to start on page 1 and being continued on page 2?

Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[preprint, authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\captionsetup[table]{
    labelsep = newline, labelfont={small}, justification=centering, textfont={bf,small}
}
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.4ex}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]\par
\footnotesize
\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}[para, flushleft]
\lipsum[1-2]
    \end{TableNotes}
    \centering
    \begin{longtable}{l r r r r }
        \caption{Title}\\
        \insertTableNotes\\
        \hline
        \hline
        &XXX&XXX&XXX&XXX\Tstrut\\
        \hline
        \underline{\textit{Panel A}}&&&&\Tstrut\\
        \underline{\textit{vvv}}&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\Tstrut\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        \underline{\textit{ccc}}&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\Tstrut\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        \underline{\textit{Panel B}}&&&&\Tstrut\\
        \underline{\textit{vvv}}&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\Tstrut\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        \underline{\textit{ccc}}&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\Tstrut\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        \hline
        &YYY&YYY&YYY &YYY\Tstrut\\
            \hline
        \underline{\textit{Panel A}}&&&&\Tstrut\\
        \underline{\textit{vvv}}&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\Tstrut\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        \underline{\textit{ccc}}&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\Tstrut\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        \underline{\textit{Panel B}}&&&&\Tstrut\\
        \underline{\textit{vvv}}&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\Tstrut\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        \underline{\textit{ccc}}&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\Tstrut\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        ZZZ&&&&\\
        \hline
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}\label{1234}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Longtable already supports footnotes.  You don't need ThreePartTable.